# JavaScript error on Stack Overflow page causing it to not work properly on Chrome

Tags: bug, javascript, google-chrome

My Stack Overflow account is not showing any option in the description box from today:

[image]

And the reputation notification icon and message notification are not working. It's not showing anything. The notification window is not opening, only on my Stack Overflow.

*Still yesterday it was working good. It's append only today.*

[image]

And also the `runnable was missing`. See the image; the first one was missing the run button.

[image]

**What append?**

> If I click the icon only `#` is added with end of the URL.

**Details**

- Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Error**

> full.en.js?v=4927e96fa177:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

How can I fix this? I could not do anything on my Stack Overflow page.

Comment: [status-norepro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bVKb.png)

Comment: Sometime its suddenly disabled .After logout and reset my chrome ,Its working .I need to know whats the problem?

Comment: is there any other error in console?

Comment: no its just one of the error i was posted.

Comment: Things to try: 1) Incognito mode of Chrome. 2) Disable all extension/userscripts/plugins of Chrome. 3) Try different browser.